# Python+MySQLConnector: Substitution in query results in an error

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I used MySQL Connector/Python API, NOT MySQLdb.

I need to dynamically insert values into a sparse table so I wrote the Python code like this:

```
cur.executemany("UPDATE myTABLE SET %s=%s WHERE id=%s" % data)
```

where

```
data=[('Depth', '17.5cm', Decimal('3003')), ('Input_Voltage', '110 V AC', Decimal('3004'))]
```

But it resulted an error:

`TypeError: not enough arguments for format string`

Is there any solution for this problem? Is it possible to use `executemany` when there is a
substitution of a field in query?

Thanks.

Comment: Always post the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the original method:

As the error message suggests you have a problem with your SQL syntax (not Python). If you insert your values you are effectively trying to execute

```sql
UPDATE myTABLE SET 'Depth'='17.5cm' WHERE id='3003'
```

You should notice that you are trying to assign a value to a string `'Depth'`, not a database field. The reason for this is that the `%s` substitution of the mysql module is only possible for values, not for tables/fields or other object identifiers.

In the second try you are not using the substitution anymore. Instead you use generic python string interpolation, which however looks similar. This does not work for you because you have a `,` and a pair of brackets too much in your code. It should read:

```
cur.execute("UPDATE myTABLE SET %s=%s WHERE id=%s" % data)
```

I also replaced `executemany` with `execute` because this method will work only for a single row. However your example only has one row, so there is no need to use `executemany` anyway.

The second method has some drawbacks however. The substitution is not guaranteed to be quoted or formatted in a correct manner for the SQL query, which might cause unexpected behaviour for certain inputs and may be a security concern.

I would rather ask, why it is necessary to provide the field name dynamically in the first place. This should not be necessary and might cause some trouble.

Comment: Please post the full error traceback. Did you change the line `data = ('Depth','17.5cm',Decimal('3003'))`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But using your code resulted a new error: "TypeError: not enough arguments for format string". I am new in both python and mysql, so I am not quite sure about the error message meaning... Is it because the format of 'data'?

Comment: `data` is from another table. `print(data)` gives `('Depth', '17.5"', Decimal('237603'))`

Comment: What about the error traceback? The substitution should be fine, there are three values in data and three `%s` in the query.

Comment: Sorry for the misleading. The error is `mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '" WHERE model_id=3003' at line 1`

Comment: You have a typo in `('Depth', '17.5"', Decimal('237603'))`. Is the `"` also in your code? It doesn't belong there.

Comment: If `data=[('Depth', '17.5cm', Decimal('3003')), ('Input_Voltage', '110 V AC', Decimal('3004'))]` and I execute `cur.executemany("UPDATE myTABLE SET %s=%s WHERE id=%s" % data)` the error will be `TypeError: not enough arguments for format string`

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, you cannot use the second method if you have multiple rows. Use a for loop `for row in data: cur.executemany("UPDATE myTABLE SET %s=%s WHERE id=%s" % row)`. Why is the `Depth` and `Input_Voltage` a field anyway? It should be a value.

Comment: Yes. it's a typo, it should be '17cm'. But it's not the reason of the syntax error, is it?

Comment: Yes it is...
Also `17cm` will give you a problem, because as I said it will not be quoted correctly if you use the second method. And then there is also the type issue. What mysql type is `Depth`?

Comment: The reason I used `executemany` instead of for loop is that I have ~1,500,000 records to update. The running time of the for loop is too long (updating 500 records takes 1hr in my computer). Is there any other solution?

Comment: `Depth` and `Input_Voltage` is the names of the columns of `myTABLE`

Comment: Yes, but what types do the columns have?

Comment: the type of `Depth` and all other fields is mediumtext.

Comment: ok then, that is fine. I cannot help you any further as the discussion already lost the original question.